# Loop through all images and change size?

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, blogger

The script below works for posts that are already on the page. But, when I click on load more posts, the new posts that get added to the page don't change the source of the image so that they are blurry.

Is there a way to loop through all images and change the `src` of it, even the ones that are not shown?

```
function resizeThumb(size) {
    var popularPost = document.getElementById('Blog1');
    var image = popularPost.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        image[i].src = image[i].src.replace(/\/s72\-c/g, "\/s" + size + "-c");
        image[i].width = size;
        image[i].height = size;
    }
}
// Resize to 200 × 200
resizeThumb(200);
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your code again, it is messed up. Are you writing code in a word processor?

Comment: Then just call the function again from the load more posts, after it is done.

Comment: How are the new images being added to the page? Do you control that process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Basically locate the button that loads more, find it's name.

If your button looks like this:

```
 <a href="javascript:loadmore();"> Load more </a>
```

Put this before it so it looks like this:

```
 <span onclick="resizeThumb(200); "> 
      <a href="javascript:loadmore();"> Load more </a>
 </span>
```

It's the lousiest solution but the question is lousy too.

Comment: When it loads the first time the images are still blurry.The second click triggers the function for the images that have been loaded, but the newly loaded images are blurry and so on.